# Codeigniter blank page on error. How do I get a descriptive error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to see the errors thrown by my code in order to fix it. I've looked this error and found some stuff, like putting the following lines in the index method of the controller:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'testing');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I've also seen that the 'display_errors' is suppoused to be edited in the php.ini and that there is set by default as true.

Aparently this isn't enough. Any ideas?

I'm using codeigniter 3.1.11 and XAMPP

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.11

Answer (score 0):

try in index.php

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

and remove old code you added for error reporting

EDIT:
try adding in php.ini and restart apache server on xammp

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

still does not work add a .htaccess file in root of application with code inside

```
# Displaying PHP errors
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean to add that in the index method, because I don't have any index.php file. I have other controllers file. I've already tried to add that there, with no luck

Comment: not in index method.. the index.php file in root of your application

Comment: I completely forgot about it. I've done what you said with no luck. I've tried with testing there with the same result

Comment: Didn't work. The display errors was already on. I tried adding the other things and didn't work either. I'm having a warning message when I restart xampp that /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf was ignored. Checking it out, seems like a mysql file so it shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying, I realized there were 2 problems:

1) Trying to clean the project, I deleted the folder views/errors thinking it was simply for good practice. Now I know that the log I see is there. 
2) The other thing was file permissions. After

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/$project
```

It worked fine.

Thanks to the people that tried helping me. Hope this works for someone else

Answer (score -1):

in your index.php 
change

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'production');
```

to

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Comment: Didn't work, although I understand that it's better than what I did